# SmartyStreets Cloud API implementation

Tags: php, ajax, smartystreets

I wrote a simple API to verify addresses using SmartyStreets API. I currently have a free account with them to do the testing.

The API works as it is but I would like to implement two other features.
1- autocomplete addresses and populate values in the form.
2- use Ajax so the page allows the user to type the address, sends the request to SmartStreets, get the response, and display the result along with the form, empty this time, to allow the user to enter another addess. Here is the code I wrote.

My question is: Is it possible to implement autocomplete with this script and make it submit to the same page and show the form after submission for a second lookup? If possible, I just need a guide or resources. Thanks!

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['address']) && isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $address = urlencode($_GET['address']);
    $city = urlencode($_GET['city']);
    $state = urlencode($_GET['state']);
    $json = file_get_contents('https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id=auth_id_goes_here&auth-token=auth_token_goes_here&street='.$address.'&city='.$city.'&state='.$state.'&candidates=10');
    $output = json_decode($json, $assoc=true);
    //var_dump($output);
    if (!empty($output)) {
        echo 'This address is good!<br>';
        echo $output[0]['delivery_line_1'].'<br>';
        echo $output[0]['last_line'];
    } else {
        echo 'This address is bad!<br>';
        echo $_GET['address'].'<br>';
        echo $_GET['city'].' '.$_GET['state'];
    }
} else {
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>SmartyStreets Address Verifier</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            function verify() {
                if(!document.getElementsByName("address")[0].value) {
                    window.alert("Street Address is required!");
                    return false;
                }
                if(!document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value) {
                    window.alert("City cannot be empty!");
                    return false;
                }
                if(!document.getElementsByName("state")[0].value) {
                    window.alert("State cannot be empty!");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <h1>SmartyStreets Address Verifier</h1>
        <hr>
        <h3>Please enter the information below then click Verify.</h3>
        <table><tr><td><table><tr><td>
            <form action="index.php" onsubmit="return verify()" method="GET">
                <table><tr><td><table><tr>
                    <td>Street Address: </td><td>
                        <input type="text" name="address" value="" /><font color="red">*</font>
                    </td></tr><tr><td>
                        City: </td><td>
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="" /><font color="red">*</font>
                    </td></tr><tr><td>
                        State: </td><td>
                        <input type="text" name="state" value="" /><font color="red">*</font>
                    </td></tr><tr><td>
                        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
                    </td><td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Ask a question please.

Comment: My question is: Is it possible to implement autocomplete with this script and make it submit to the same page and show the form after submission for a second lookup? If possible, I just need a guide or resources. Thanks!

Comment: @HussamHallak, I work for SmartyStreets. Have you tried implementing that script already? Are you having any problems doing so?

Comment: @SunSparc I implemented the API and it works, but I was hoping to make it better by using the autocomplete feature and make the page submits to itself. At this point, the API works fine but without these features. My boss did not care for those features as long as the API works so I left it like that.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like the [https://smartystreets.com/demo](SmartyStreets Demo page)?

Comment: That link did not work: It gave me this message: This Page is Not Available…
But Savannah is…

Comment: @HussamHallak The link is https://smartystreets.com/demo